# I want to monitor global mouse event, how to do it by using MFC?

Tags: mfc

I want to write a program:

- click a window(some other program, like firefox, explorer..)
- get this window's HWND
- do something to that window

My method is using PeekMessage to get event, but looks like PeekMessage only peek the message send from my program.

So how can I add a hook to all the other windows, or monitor global events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetWindowsHookEx`, with the `WH_MOUSE` or possibly `WH_MOUSE_LL` flag. MFC itself doesn't really have much to do with this, at least to my recollection (though, behind the scenes, MFC can/does install a hook, or maybe even more than one, itself).